# Deploy my Webapp in SOLR Default Jetty Container

Tags: solr, jetty

I have a simple web app that runs well in tomcat as well as jetty. So far, it queries a solr instance that run in a separate container. The solr container is the default Jetty that comes with solr.

I am trying to merge my app and solr so I don't have to maintain two separate servlet containers. The option that I seem to favor is to have my app run within the solr default container.

To do this, I take my app and drop it in the example/webapps folder. Unfortunately, this jetty version does not seem to pick it up. All it picks up from that folder is the solr war file.

What am I missing? How do I get this container to pick my app or where should I drop my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context xml has to be defined for new application similar to the one in example/contexts/solr-jetty-context.xml

Comment: was trying to deploy a web application in the embedded Jetty container by putting it under `${jetty.home}/webapps` which, according to Jetty documentation, should work...but it doesn't...only using a separate context.xml file worked...and this pretty much confirmed my findings.